# Windows shortcut (.lnk) filesize

Tags: windows, shortcut, filesize, lnk

The size of shortcut (`.lnk`) files on my computer (Windows 7) ranges from 235 to 15,881 bytes, with an average of 2,395 bytes.

In [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx) of the shortcut file format, it contains an extraordinary amount of information, including attributes, timestamps, and filesize of the target file, and a lot more. The structure is quite complex and I haven't used it to analyze the contents of my shortcut files. But in the latest version of the documentation file, section 3 gives a structure example that has length x01CA = 458 bytes. So most of my shortcut files are several times larger than their example.

The only information I provide when I create a shortcut is the filespec (path and filename) of the target. Why is there such a large variation in the sizes of the resulting shortcut files? What is in the larger files that is not in the smaller ones? And why are most shortcuts so much larger than the documented example?

I've found two sources online that discuss the shortcut format ([1](https://ithreats.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/lnk_the_windows_shortcut_file_format.pdf) ([link](https://ithreats.net/2009/05/27/window-shortcut-lnk-file-format/)), [2](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/09/dissecting-a-shortcut/)). Both provide examples that are quite small files, and neither says anything about what would cause typical shortcuts to be much larger.

Comment: There are three text fields (Target, Working Dir and Comment). Additionally you can provide a different symbol, which is also a text. All these texts can have arbitrary lengths and depending on the source file they are pointing to, the size could differ (cause all the paths are saved as full path not as relative).

Comment: I've never added a comment to a shortcut, and the two other text fields cannot possibly account for even a single kilobyte, never mind 15 kb.

Comment: Do I understand Oliver correctly that the different 'symbol' is the size of the icon?  I am curious because while transferring some old drives the 'my documents' shortcut (linked to the new documents folder) is not transferring and it causes my size comparisons to get thrown off.  Why not ask one more thing; are the old 'My Documents', 'My Music' folders .ink, symbolic links, or junctions?  They show as junctions in cmd dir /a:l /s . Thanks.